# Inconsistent size of binary file with doubles (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, double, binaryfiles

I'm having problems writing and reading an array of doubles into a binary file. In some cases the size of the file is greater than expected. The following code:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, size=13;
    FILE *fid = fopen("C:\\Group0\\Night0\\Imanti\\test.dat", "w");
    double *arr = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)* size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = size / (i + 1.0);
        printf("%f\n", arr[i]);
    }

    fwrite(arr, sizeof(double), size, fid);
    free(arr);
    fclose(fid);
    printf("\n\n");

    fid = fopen("C:\\Group0\\Night0\\Imanti\\test.dat", "r");
    arr = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)* size);
    fread(arr, sizeof(double), size, fid);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr);
    fclose(fid);

    return 0;
}
```

shows a simple example of my problem. If I run it with for example `size = 10`, the size of the file is 80 bytes and the numbers are the same at writing and reading. If I run it with `size = 13`, the size of the file is 105 bytes (when it should be 104 bytes) and the numbers are completely different. The output of the case with `size = 13` is:

```
13.000000
6.500000
4.333333
3.250000
2.600000
2.166667
1.857143
1.625000
1.444444
1.300000
1.181818
1.083333
1.000000


13.000000
-6108112916776316800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
-6277438562204192500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
-6277438562204192500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
-6277438562204192500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
-6277438562204192500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
-6277438562204192500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
-6277438562204192500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
-6277438562204192500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
-6277438562204192500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
-6277438562204192500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
-6277438562204192500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
-6277438562204192500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

Either the first number (13) or the second one (6.5) is written with an extra byte, causing the file to be larger and the reading to fail. I know double representation can lead to precision errors, but as far as I can tell this is not about precision as is the size of the double variable in the file what is changing.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something really obvious here, but it has driven me crazy already. I'm using vs2013 on an i7 computer.

Comment: Good question. However I'm a bit interested. The hex representation of your double numbers are `13.000000: 402a000000000000 6.500000: 401a000000000000 4.333333: 4011555555555555 3.250000: 400a000000000000 2.600000: 4004cccccccccccd...`. As you're working with Windows on which the line-ending '\n' (0x0A) would be converted to `\n\r` (0x0D0A) in text mode, I suppose malformed values in the output shall start from `3.25` or its next one. However your results shows it starts from `6.5`. Could you please post the binary content of your file `test.dat`? Your could use some editor like `HxD`. Thx.

Comment: This is the hex dump of the 13 case:

'00 00 00 00 00 00 2a 40 
00 00 00 00 00 00 1a 40 
55 55 55 55 55 55 11 40 
00 00 00 00 00 00 0d 0a 
40 cd cc cc cc cc cc 04 
40 55 55 55 55 55 55 01 
40 6e db b6 6d db b6 fd 
3f 00 00 00 00 00 00 fa 
3f c7 71 1c c7 71 1c f7 
3f cd cc cc cc cc cc f4 
3f e9 a2 8b 2e ba e8 f2 
3f 55 55 55 55 55 55 f1 
3f 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 
3f'

Now I'm guessing that when I was reading the file in text mode, the first byte of the second number was ommited as it was interpreted as an end line, that's why the error would show up starting from the second number.

Comment: Thank you. I'm busy writing something to my supervisor but after a brief view I think my suspect is true that the first three numbers in your file is not affected by the line-ending. Then it's really interesting why your output fails from the second number. I'll come back later. Anyone please point out any mistake you found in my thought.

Comment: Maybe not. Differences between text and binary mode of buffered IO in C affects how the line-ending is interpreted (`\n` `\r\n` or `\r`) but nothing would be "omitted". Also the byte is `0x1A` not `0x0D0A`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are working with binary data, you may need to specify binary mode for the file operations:

```
FILE *fid = fopen("C:\\Group0\\Night0\\Imanti\\test.dat", "wb");

fid = fopen("C:\\Group0\\Night0\\Imanti\\test.dat", "rb");
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious. Is working great, thanks!

Comment: Why I run this code on my machine correctly? (openSUSE, gcc, i3)

Comment: @xingouy How is end-of-line represented in text files on your machine?

Comment: Good answer. Please read my comment under the OP's question if interested. I don't use Windows currently neither have some virtual machine to test with for now.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I think it's ended by LF, you mean the program read in the EOF?

Comment: So you were right, the EOF (0x1A) is what was making the problem appear in the second number and not in 3.25 where 0x0D was inserted before 0x0A.

Comment: @xingouy Linux doesn't do text translation by default. Windows does. Given his path names, he was working under Windows.